# Unity 2D Sprite rotate toward object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am making this game in unity. It is a 2d race car game where the player is a racer and has to navigate through the road avoiding crashing into cones or other other cars that are also driving on the road. I've created a path for the other NPC cars that are driving on the road and that part works. Those cars follow the path the way I want them to. But what I want to do now is make the NPC car sprites rotate towards the next path point.

So for example if the vehicle is switching lanes or turning a corner, the car should rotate and point towards the next point in their path. This is the code I have:

```
public Transform[] waypoints;   //array to hold all the waypoints in the sprite's path

    [SerializeField]
    public float moveSpeed = 2.0f;

    public int wayPointIndex = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = waypoints[wayPointIndex].transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }

    public void Move(){
        if(wayPointIndex <= waypoints.Length - 1){
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[wayPointIndex].transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            if(transform.position == waypoints[wayPointIndex].transform.position){
                wayPointIndex+=1;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a bird's eye view game by the way. So the vehicles are seen from the top down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the transform.rotate method. The method uses an angle input, you could calculate the desired angle geometrically with your current orientation angle and the angle to the next waypoint.

Comment: I already tried that. Plus idk if that would work well because there’s gonna be like ten different objects of this class with 10 different sets of waypoints

Comment: Do you have a separate script for your NPC's? If not then you should do this and then update the NPC movement in there. Why different sets of waypoints? Its always the same points, your NPC instances just reach them at different times

Comment: No this is the script for the NPC cars. And they have to be different sets fo waypoints because for example, one car could literally just be going straight up the road. Another car could also go up the road, but then make a left turn. and then another could make a right right turn and then a left turn. So I just want the car sprite to turn (rotate) towards the next waypoint . This is going to be used for if a car makes a right or left turn as I stated previously.

Comment: What I have been doing right now, which is way too time consuming, is creating separate animations for each car object when they turn a corner or switch lanes. So when it reaches the waypoint at the corner of the block for example, it plays the rotation animation. This has been working so far, but like I said it is way too time consuming. Especially when I have to animate every rotation for like 10 to 20 different NPC vehicles in 5 different stages.

Comment: Ok so your problem now is basically "How do I make my code more scalable". If you want a custom animation for every turn of a specific NPC sprite, then yes this will cost you a lot of time. When you use many similar objects, I would suggest using prefabs. Can't you just use the same animation with a customizable sprite? (Ask a separate question on SO for this)

Comment: Actually yea that makes a lot of sense

Comment: Cool! So your question is answered?

Comment: Yes! I greatly appreciate the help!